# Cygwin: cannot run / error when in X11 xterm with OpenGL / GLEW libraries

Tags: opengl, cygwin, x11, glew, freeglut

I am working with X11 opengl on Cygwin and trying to run some tests on using the glew library.

Trying to compile the "Chapter2.4.c" example from [here](http://openglbook-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter%202/)

It compiles without errors. But when trying to run from x11 (startxwin) at xterm, I get the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
Major opcode of failed request:  148 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
Serial number of failed request:  21
Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

Any idea why this is happening? May it be something to do with the nvidia / x11 mismatch in library / headers as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052624/glcreateshader-returns-0-need-help-debugging)?

Comment: You mean you are using Cygwin in linux or Cygwin in windows and trying to run X11 on windows?

Answer (score 1):

> GLXBadFBConfig

Cygwin's X11 server does not support the features required for extended window FBConfigs to be selected, and that's exactly what this message tells you. If you're running on Windows the best course of action is to use OpenGL natively.