# What can cause glCreateShader to return 0 at some points?

Tags: opengl

I'm running into a very strange OpenGL bug, where calling `glCreateShader` works several times, and then at a later point I try to call it and it fails, returning 0.  Calling `glGetError` immediately afterwards also returns 0, indicating no error.  Searching around, I see [questions about `glCreateShader` never working,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052624/glcreateshader-returns-0-need-help-debugging) which is not the case here, and a few people mentioning that it can return 0 if called between `glBegin` and `glEnd`, which I'm not using.  Looking around, I don't see any obvious things in the call stack that should indicate I'm doing something strange with OpenGL.

`glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns "4.3.0 - Build 10.18.10.3977", in case that helps.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This reeks of no OpenGL context being bound to the calling thread. You didn't specify which OS you're on, but you can use `wglGetCurrentContext` on Windows, `glXGetCurrentContext` on X11 (most likely Linux) to query which context is currently bound (or not at all).

If either function returns `NULL` then there's no OpenGL context arond and you'll get the behaviour you described.

Comment: That was the problem, all right.  The code in question was supposed to only run on the main threat, but it got invoked in a worker threat due to a bug, and the call stack was deep enough that I didn't immediately notice.  Thanks!